# Wordpress display custom taxonomy image on single post - php

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

**I´m trying to display a custom taxonomy image in the frontend on a single post.**

Following situation:

1. Created a CPT for "Weine"
2. Added a taxonomy "winzer"
3. Added the following code to my functions.php to display the "winemaker" taxonomy with its description in the single post using a shortcode:

```
function wpb_catlist_desc() { 
$string = '<div>';
$catlist = get_terms( 'winzer' );
if ( ! empty( $catlist ) ) {
  foreach ( $catlist as $key => $item ) {
    $string .= '<div>'. $item->name . '<br />';
    $string .= '<em>'. $item->description . '</em></div>';
  }
}
$string .= '</div>';
 
return $string; 
}
add_shortcode('wpb_categories', 'wpb_catlist_desc');
```

4. Added an Image fieled to the "winzer" taxonomy using ACF. --> **Here´s where I´m stuck now**.

I need to add another line to the php snippet to also display the image using the shortcode.

Any hints how to get this done? :)

Cheers!!!!

Comment: See [this](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/). Basically you should be able to call `get_field('image_field_name_here', $item)` inside of your loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress CPT Display Taxonomy Description in single post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67574444/wordpress-cpt-display-taxonomy-description-in-single-post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got it solved:

```
function wpb_catlist_desc() { 
global $post;   
$string = '<div>';
$catlist = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'winzer');


if ( ! empty( $catlist ) ) {
        foreach ($catlist as $item ) {
            $image = get_field('winzer_bild', 'winzer_'.$item->term_id);
            if(!empty($image)) {
                $imgurl = $image['url'];
            }
            $string .= '<div>';
            $string .= '<img class="winzer-bild-klein" src="' . $imgurl . '" alt="' . $item->name . '"style="width:100%;"/>';
            $string .= '<h3 class="winzer-name-n">'. $item->name . '</h3>';
            $string .= '<p>'. $item->description . '</p></div>';

        }
    }
    $string .= '</div>';
 
    return $string; 
}
add_shortcode('wpb_categories', 'wpb_catlist_desc');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function wpb_catlist_desc() { 
    $string = '<div>';
    $catlist = get_terms( 'winzer' );
    if ( ! empty( $catlist ) ) {
        foreach ( $catlist as $key => $item ) {
            $image = get_field('Your_image_field_ID');
            if(!empty($image)) {
                $imgurl = $image['url'];
            }

            $string .= '<div>';
            $string .= '<img src="' . $imgurl . '" alt="' . $item->name . '"/><br />';
            $string .= $item->name . '<br />';
            $string .= '<em>'. $item->description . '</em></div>';
        }
    }
    $string .= '</div>';
 
    return $string; 
}
add_shortcode('wpb_categories', 'wpb_catlist_desc');
```

Comment: Thanks for that :) Didn´t get it working yet... From where di I get the 'Your_image_field-ID'?

Comment: So I tried it with the field name and also inspected the backend which told me the field name:  acf[field_609edf9d70e05]   --> Tried it without the brackets and the "acf" and the "field_" , but nothing worked....