# Wordpress custom post type how to display taxonomy description in single post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

**I´m trying to display a custom taxonomy item description in the frontend on a single post.**

Following situation:

1. Created a CPT for "Weine"
2. Added a taxonomy "winzer"
3. Added the following code to my functions.php to display the "winzer" taxonomy item with its description in the single post using a shortcode:

```
function wpb_catlist_desc() { 
$string = '<div>';
$catlist = get_terms( 'winzer' );
if ( ! empty( $catlist ) ) {
  foreach ( $catlist as $key => $item ) {
    $string .= '<div>'. $item->name . '<br />';
    $string .= '<em>'. $item->description . '</em></div>';
  }
}
$string .= '</div>';
 
return $string; 
}
add_shortcode('wpb_categories', 'wpb_catlist_desc');
```

The code is working well, but it’s displaying all the items I created in the “Winzer” Taxonomy.

I just want to display the Item which is related to the single post.

Any ideas on how to change the code to get this done?

Cheers!!!!

Comment: Try using get_the_terms() instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `get_the_terms()` instead of using `get_terms()`. So you could do something like this:

```php
add_shortcode('wpb_categories', 'wpb_catlist_desc');

$the_id_of_current_post = get_the_ID(); // get the id of the current post

// pass the id to your function
function wpb_catlist_desc($the_id_of_current_post) 
{ 
  $string = '<div>';
  
  $$catlist = get_the_terms( $the_id_of_current_post, 'winzer' );

  if ( ! empty( $catlist ) ) {
    foreach ( $catlist as $cat ) {
      $string .= '<div>'. $cat->name . '<br />';
      $string .= '<em>'. $cat->description . '</em></div>';
    }
  }

  $string .= '</div>';
  
  return $string; 
}
```

Or an alternative way would be something like this:

```php
add_shortcode('wpb_categories', 'wpb_catlist_desc');

function wpb_catlist_desc() 
{ 
  global $post;

  $the_id_of_current_post = $post->ID; // get the id of the current post

  $string = '<div>';
  
  $$catlist = get_the_terms( $the_id_of_current_post, 'winzer' );

  if ( ! empty( $catlist ) ) {
    foreach ( $catlist as $cat ) {
      $string .= '<div>'. $cat->name . '<br />';
      $string .= '<em>'. $cat->description . '</em></div>';
    }
  }

  $string .= '</div>';
  
  return $string; 
}
```

Let me know if you were able to get this to work!